# Unknown network interface name showing

Tags: networking, docker, ifconfig

On my Ubuntu 22.04 installation, when I check my IP details, a network interface I neither use nor recognize is showing. (See attached screenshot)

Note that I have not installed docker, but one docker network interface is showing.

How can I find which network interface is the default and which ones are attached to my computer?

Thanks.

[ifconfig-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFJYd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Q: *[H]ow to find which network interface is default & attached to my installed software*

A: Look at the IP address for each listed interface. Compare that to the IP address range issued by your router.

Let's pretend that you are using the default dhcp and that you are using a typical home router that issues IP addresses in the range 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254. Looking at your output, that's a fairly safe assumption.

- An interface with an IP address of 192.168.59.1 is **not** in that range. That interface is **not** connected to your router.
- An interface with an IP address of 10.104.38.1 is **not** in that range. That interface is **not** connected to your router.
- An interface with an IP address of 192.168.1.103 **IS** in that range. That interface **is** connected to your router. That is your internet connection.